# Send a POST request with XML from C++ in BB10

Tags: xml, post, blackberry-10

Hi I want to send a HTTP Post request with XML from C++ in Blackberry 10.

**How can I send the request?**

In response I will again receive an XML which I want to parse.

**Can anyone provide some information on how to parse the XML received ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For parsing look at QDomNode and its derivatives - https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qdomnode.html

Comment: thanks for your answer @barry.... but I am more concerned about sending HTTP request with XML data. I am stuck on it from last 2 hrs :(

Comment: For parsing I'd recommend xmldataaccess: https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__data__xmldataaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QNetworkAccessManager](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to send a post request with your XML data.